# Checking multiple values for nil in if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have 3 different values, and want to check to see if all of them `!= nil` in an `if` statement. If I do the following, I get a warning on the `if` line stating: `Expression result unused`.

```
NSString *title = _titleField.text;
NSString *desc = _descField.text;
UIImage *img = _postImg.image;

if (title,desc,img) {

}
```

What's the best way to check if all are nil?

Comment: `if (title && desc && img) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the expression `title,desc,img` is valid Objective-C, it does not do what you want it to do. Instead of checking all three items and returning `true` if all checks pass, it checks the items one by one, and discards all results except the last one:

> Comma is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value.

In other words, your `if` is equivalent to `if (img)`. The two other expression results are unused, so the compiler produces a warning about it.

In order to check all three for `nil`, apply `&&` operator instead of `,` operator.